# Android EditText AutoMoveing

Tags: android

Hi
 i have a EditText when writing in Editext ,some times my EditText do not move up word ,so am hard to write using the virtual keyboard, how can i manually do the auto moving of editext  up word when writing using virtual keyboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting it (or the view/layout) inside a ScrollView.

And don't fix the height of that ScrollView. When the keyboard will pop-up, it will automatically scroll the EditText up.

I prefer you should put all the views of the Activity inside that ScrollView, so that you get a more seamless experience while using the App.